How can I fake a character’s death without it being obvious she’s alive?
I’m writing a mystery novel about kids trying to solve the death of their four parents (two families). The families are billionaires and they’ve created an empire. One of the mothers ends up being the killer of the kids’ dads. The other mom’s death is later revealed to be unrelated.
The problem I have is that I want to convince readers that she is dead. The whole plot twist is that it’s their mother who was the killer and is now trying to kill them.
A rundown of the crime scene for anyone who thinks they could help:

The four billionaires had a massive party on their yacht.
Guests were escorted off the yacht by small motorboats by the end of the party (2am).
The last person to leave the boat was the staff (4am).
The four of them supposedly all went to bed/passed out from the amount of fun and alcohol.
When the chef arrived on the boat the next morning (9am) he found them all dead.
The police (who are paid off) ruled it an accident, a carbon monoxide poisoning, yet the engine was changed to electric the day before.

I beg a fellow writer to please help me figure out how to make it not obvious that she had faked her death but also who’s body was found on the yacht?
P.s I have thought of the twin sister trope and I just think its too obvious and overdone :)

I think the biggest problem is that the kids are alive and are able to identify their "mother" (a fake dead body) with 100% accuracy (unless they are also involved somehow). So the murderer woman cannot exchange bodies. Also because DNA identification and other records like dental, broken bones etc. are hard to trick, this seems to lead nowhere.
So my suggestions spin around how the murderer woman can get missing with plausible death, so there is no body to be identified.
Man... Female over board!
Because you can be at the open sea (will also work in or close to a harbor with some good explanation why the body was drifting away with the flood):
Just put a piece of ripped cloth, maybe a little blood and hair ("head injury"), a single slipper and a broken bottle of alcohol near the bulwark at some plausible spot. Don't forget to leave plenty of DNA and other proof (saliva and fingerprints on the bottle, make sure it's the cloth from the dress she was wearing that night etc). Implying she fell over board, drowned and was eaten by sharks probably. She needs to have a companion or a scuba diver gear or something that brings her off the boat (silently).
In extreme cases she might even spend a leg (amputated by a hired doctor) which is prepared to be found floating on the sea as evidence of her demise (with some shark bites applied, fake or real).
Many murderers are better than one.
Let the murderer woman leave the scene but also take (and later get rid of) another of the bodies, just to imply that there were two killed and two missing.
This can also be played a little bloody and maybe even plotted so that there are really accomplices coming to lay out the evidence of kidnappers coming on board: scratches of a boat, footprints, fake DNA, maybe even so good that CCTV shows "a real crime and kidnapping", etc.
Then forge a kidnapping video conducted by those accomplices (masked and stuff): In one video the "other body" is shown to lie in a corner (implying to be shot/died recently, but the face is not shown or only bad enough that it cannot be told if the body is dead for longer). The murderer woman is also shown tied up, beaten up and in the end (fake) shot. Maybe the videos appear in stages of increased intensity, not all at once.
The police will still search for the kidnappers and the bodies, but after a  while of unsuccessful attempts, stops searching.
Supporting ideas for the scenarios above:

Don't make them party near the coast of New York or something "highly civilized" and easy to scan. Maybe more like in the Caribbean, or some remote location. Local authorities are slow, unwilling to cooperate with external investigators and can generally be underpaid and in bad shape with bad equipment. This makes it more likely the case is closed because "not solvable" and "who cares", there is no incentive for them.

Consider who might be involved in the plan, to make it easier:

The kids (one of them maybe older and willing to fake identify her "body")?
One or two staff members (doing the "dirty work" with the others)?
Maybe her lover (which can be a plotman like the captain, or the investigator)
Just to name a few, there is surely more room to expand.




Thank you so much this is super helpful!!

"Also because DNA identification and other records like dental, broken bones etc. are hard to trick, this seems to lead nowhere." - are these tests done every time someone dies, or only when there's some doubt about their identity?

@komodosp: good point actually... to answer, we would need to know where the location is and maybe someone who knows about criminal investigation procedures, I guess. But I think, in case of (alleged) murder, an autopsy is mandatory and during an autopsy the identity of the body/person has to be determined by DNA or other court/jury acceptable proof (also by identification by close relatives for example). All evidence secured/found, will be the basis for any kind of search for the murderer (checking for motives first in the social sphere, but for this you need to verify who this body is).

For such a big party, a lot of non-permanent staff would likely be hired just for the day, so a random waitress, cleaner or kitchen help of the right age/built/complexion is a candidate for someone whose disappearance might go unnoticed.
You will need to give a thought to who identified the bodies, and whether it's possible for that person to make an honest mistake, or you need to make them an accomplice (or even the fake victim herself in disguise).
You might also want to consider whether you shouldn't make the cause of death something that changes the victim's appearance more, so the investigators might more plausibly miss a discrepancy compared to photographs and such.
I kinda doubt the police could be bribed to overlook a multiple murder; if they need to be bribed to not look too closely, it makes more sense if they believed it was an issue of neglected maintenance (which would still be a criminal homicide case, mind you, just one they might be more willing to drop).
